# Objective-c: convert array of uint8 to int32

Tags: objective-c, c, accelerate-framework

I'm looking for function which can fast convert array of **uint8**'s to **int32**'s (keeping count of numbers). 
There is already such a function to convert **uint8** to **double** in vDSP library:

```
vDSP_vfltu8D
```

How can analogous function be implemented on Objective-c (iOS, amd arch)? Pure C solutions accepted too.

Comment: what have you tried?  what was wrong with the output?  Please post the code?   Stackoverflow is to answer questions like: 'why does it not compile?' and 'why does it not produce the correct output?'   For such questions, the code must be supplied.   The current wording of the question will solicit opinions rather than definitive answers.

Comment: @user3629249, I have 1.300 points and I know what is Stackoverflow for. If you don't know what the question about because you are far from Objective-c, please don't vote down, just press "skip". What I already tried - I investigated whole Accelerate.framework and didn't find built in solution there.

Comment: If your question is regarding the `Accelerate` framework, you should add this tag.

Comment: Do you want the values to be 4 uint8s -> 1 int32 or 1 uint8 -> 1 int32 with leading zeros?

Comment: To get a clear understanding of the needed functionality:  Is this the same as `for (i=0; i<N; i++) a_int32[i] = a_uint8[i]` but fast?  Or it is something more exotic?  Is your platform a DSP or any old CPU?

Comment: The question that both AlexKoren and chux asked needs to be answered; please [edit] your question to clarify the exact nature of the conversion.

Comment: @AlexKoren, obviously, no special function required to convert 4x8 bits to 1x32. One can just change the array type.

Comment: @chux, yes I'm looking how to do it faster, may be using vector processor commands or something. Platform is iOS, arm architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, based on the comments above:

ARM's Neon SIMD/Vector library is what you're looking for, but I'm not 100% sure it's supported on iOS. Even if it was, I wouldn't recommend it. You've got a 64-bit architecture on iOS, meaning you would only be able to DOUBLE the speed of your process (because you're converting to `int32`s).

Now that is if there was a single command that could do this. There isn't. There are a few commands that would allow you to, when used in succession, load the `uint8`s into a 64-bit register, shift them and zero out the other bytes, and then store those as `int32`s. Those commands will have more overhead because it takes several operations to do it.

If you really want to look into the commands available, check them out here (again, not sure if they're supported on iOS): http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/CJAJIIGG.html

The iOS architecture isn't really built for this kind of processing. Vector commands in most cases only become useful when a computer has 256-bit registers, allowing you to load in 32 bytes at a time and operate on them simultaneously. I would recommend you go with the normal approach of converting one at a time in a loop (or maybe unwrap the loop to remove a bit of overhead like so:

```
//not syntactically correct code
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i+=4) {
    int32Array[i] = (int32)int8Array[i];
    int32Array[i + 1] = (int32)int8Array[i + 1];
    int32Array[i + 2] = (int32)int8Array[i + 2];
    int32Array[i + 3] = (int32)int8Array[i + 3];
}
```

While it's a small optimization, it removes 3/4s of the looping overhead. It won't do much, but hey, it's something.

Source: I worked on Intel's SIMD/Vector team, converting C functions to optimize on 256-bit registers. Some things just couldn't be done efficiently, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for answer, looks like there is no direct access to Neon functions on iOS. And why they operate with 128 bit vectors in their libraries? Could it involve the use of two cores of 64-bit processor?

Comment: Many of the processors created nowadays (I'm speaking from an Intel perspective which I'm guessing is somewhat consistent with other processors) have select 128 and 256 bit registers or virtual registers.

Comment: "I wouldn't recommend it. You've got a 64bit architecture on iOS, meaning you would only be able to DOUBLE the speed of your process (because you're converting to int32s)."  arm64 (and some armv7 parts) have 128b simd registers; furthermore these are superscalar machines, with ILP you can't just divide "machine width" by "result size" to get the expected vectorization speedup.  Apple's ARM implementations are *absolutely* built for simd.

Comment: There's nothing magic about 256b vectors; they increase the potential speedup, but this particular task vectorizes just as nicely for 128b vector registers as it does for 256b vectors.